# Show all data from Mysql Database by category wise using php

Tags: php, html

Currently in my php code I'm getting all `keywords` from a mysql table and showing it on a Html `td` column. It looks like the one in the following image.

[image]

Each **keyword** has an unique **keyword type**. For example it may contain php, html css, js under **Web Development** Keyword type.

So Now, I'm only printing all Keywords, not their **Keyword Type**.

I need to show **keywords** under each **keyword type**. So it should look like this :

```
Keyword Type1     Keyword Type2    Keyword Type3   Keyword Type4  and so on...           
html              wp               js              php 
mysql             html5            jquery          c
css               css3             xml             c++
```

How can I show this in php ?

**My existing php code is the following :**

```
<?php
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT keywords . *, keyword_type . * FROM keywords LEFT JOIN keyword_type ON keywords.keyword_typeID = keyword_type.keyword_typeID  ORDER BY kid DESC");
echo "<div id='keywordBox'>";

echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1055">';
$count = 0;
while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){

  if($count%6==0 && $count!=0){    
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }elseif($count==0)
    echo "<tr>";

    $kid = $result['kid'];
    $keywordName = ucfirst($result['keywordName']);
    $keyword_short_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_short_name']); // keyword type
    $keyword_full_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_full_name']);  // keyword type full name 

    $query2 =  mysql_query("SELECT kid FROM userkeywords WHERE cdid = '$cdid' AND kid='$kid'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($query2);

    if($num > 0){
        $class = "keywordHigligh";  
    }else{
        $class = "";
    }

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='kid' value='$kid'/>";    
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='cdid' value='$cdid'/>";  
    echo "<td width='400' onclick='keywordclick($kid,$cdid)' class='$class'><strong>$keywordName</td>";

    $count++;  
}

echo '</table>';
echo "</div>";
echo "<a href='../index.php?redcdid=$cdid'><input type='submit' value='Save' class='submit' /></a>"
?>
```

**Note:**

```
$keyword_short_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_short_name']); // keyword type
$keyword_full_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_full_name']);  // keyword type full name
```

Thanks for your suggestion and help. --Shibbir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try performing your transformation onto another array like so:

```
$output = array();
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $output[$keyword["type"]][] = $keyword["name"];
}

var_dump($output);
```

[Edit]
I was bored so I wrote this.
It is commented but let me know if you want me to clarify something.

```
<?php

$keywords = array(
    array("name" => "html", "type" => "front-end"),
    array("name" => "css", "type" => "front-end"),
    array("name" => "css", "type" => "front-end"),
    array("name" => "php", "type" => "back-end"),
    array("name" => "java", "type" => "back-end"),
    array("name" => "analytics", "type" => "marketing"),
    array("name" => "algebra", "type" => "maths"),
);

// Here we're looking to go from the above format to something like this:
// array("front-end" => array("html", "css"), "back-end" => array("php", "java") ...)
$keywordTypes = array();
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $keywordTypes[$keyword["type"]][] = $keyword["name"];
}

// Not every keyword type will have the same number of keywords so we need a height that we will all fill them to
// array_map will create an array with a count for every keyword type and max will take the longest.
$nbRows = max(array_map("count", $keywordTypes));
?>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- We iterate over all the keyword types in order to write our table headings -->
        <?php foreach($keywordTypes as $keywordType => $relatedKeywords): ?>
        <th><?php echo $keywordType ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- We know how many rows we are working with so let's use a for loop -->
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $nbRows; ++$i): ?>
    <tr>
        <!-- This foreach will display one of each keyword type as we are writing row by row -->
        <?php foreach($keywordTypes as $keywords): ?>
            <!-- If we do not have a keyword, let's still add a placeholder so the table looks right -->
            <td><?php if(isset($keywords[$i])) { echo $keywords[$i]; } ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```